# Is it possible to sending a streaming response from a simple Ruby / Rack app?

Tags: ruby, rack

I'm building a Ruby web service which accepts POST or PUT requests that tell it to do some work. The work involves moving some big files around - sometimes over a network - so these requests could take a while. I'm building a separate service - in Python, or Node, or whatever - that handles scheduling & monitoring requests to the Ruby service.

I'd like to send some kind of periodical progress report on the behaviour of the Ruby app back to the scheduler. Perhaps a line every time a discrete operation is completed successfully, such as the moving of one file.

Is this possible with a standard Rack app? FYI I'm using the Camping framework It's not dissimilar from Sinatra, etc. Usually you send the response by just returning from the method:

```
def get
   @status = 404
   @headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
   return Yajl::Encoder.new.encode({error: 'forbidden', reason: 'I don't like you'})
end
```

I know that my process is managed by the Rack / web server interface, so I don't know whether it's possible in Rack to send a streaming response without digging into the way the framework works and talks to Rack. Can someone give me some pointers here?

And yes, I know that Ruby isn't a preferred solution for streaming HTTP servers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a [chunked transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). There is a `Rack::Chunked` middleware for it too within Rack.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm gonna have to stop trying to fit this kind of stuff into a Rack-based web framework, though.

Answer (score 1):

The [Goliath](http://goliath.io) framework handles streaming responses. Take a look at [the content_stream](https://github.com/postrank-labs/goliath/blob/master/examples/content_stream.rb) example. There is no reason why Ruby isn't a preferred solution for streaming responses, we used Goliath at PostRank for some pretty heavy weight streaming services.